# Javascript populating list into html select repeating list twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery ajax to populate a html select. 
The populating actually works but the problem is that for some reason the whole list is being added twice instead of just once.

Here is the code:

```
myfunction: function() {  
    $.ajax({    
            url: 'the-url-here',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(result) { 
                $.each(result.cars, function(result, value) {
                    if (value.active === '1'){
                        $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.name).attr('value', value.id));
                    } 
                });
            }
    });
}
```

How can I fix this so it's only populated once and not twice?

Comment: Can you post sample json data??

Comment: Is it possible that **myfunction** is being invoked twice?

Comment: Probably the function is called twice. To check that, you can mark a breakpoint success function at browser.

Comment: You can try using`$('#myselect').empty();` before each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myfunction is being called twice somewhere, and since an append does what it is supposed to do (appends to your list), it's working as intended :)

Check if the value is already added before trying to add it:

```
$.each(result.cars, function(result, value) {
                if (value.active === '1' && $('#myselect option[value='+ value.id +']').length == 0) {
                    $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.name).attr('value', value.id));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting the element in the loop, which causes performance issues when the list is big, select it outside the loop, then create your list of `<options>` and outside the loop, append to the `<select>`.

```js
(function($){$(function(){
  var carsDataFetchViaAjax = [
    {id: 1, active: 1, name: 'Car1'},
    {id: 2, active: 1, name: 'Car2'},
    {id: 3, active: 0, name: 'Car3'}
  ]
  
  var $select = $('#select'), 
      options = [];
  
  carsDataFetchViaAjax.map(function(car, i){
    if (car.active == 1){
      options.push($('<option>').val(car.id).html(car.name))
    }
  })

  $select.append(options);
    
})})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select"></select>
```

---